# PHP json_encode assigns null instead of value?

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have a CSV file that looks like this:

http://ideone.com/YWuuWx

I read the file and convert it to array, which works completely fine, but then I jsonize the array - **but json_encode doesnt put the real values - it puts null** - here is the dump of the array and jsonized array:

http://jave.jecool.net/stackoverflowdemos/csv_to_json_to_arraydump.php

I convert like this: `$php_array= json_encode($json_array,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);`

anyone knows what might cause the problem?

**EDIT:** I think ther is like 90% chance that its caused by the latin1 characters - anyone knows the best workaround?

Comment: not really, those characters will be encoded too, in your case it will become `D\u0159evo`

Comment: Well this somehow does not happen - see this https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49588 someone already had this problem, however htmlentities doesnt help my problem it evens return empty string x)

Comment: Did you actually check with json_last_error() to see if it's an encoding error?

Comment: try encoding your text as UTF-8 rather than Latin1.

Comment: @TML last error says "Error: 5" , - Spudley - Latin1 is a character set not an encoding, its encoded in UTF-8 ... the CSV file && Ive even turned on mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); just to be sure...

Comment: ISO 8859 defines "a set of...graphic characters **and the coded representation of these characters by means of a single 8-bit byte**" (from ISO/IEC 8859-1:1997 (E) ); "Latin1" could mean any number of things, but in this context it shouldn't be a stretch to interpret "Latin1" as valid short-hand for ISO-8859-1 (which is *both* a character set *and* an encoding).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that it is in fact an encoding error, and that your data is actually encoded in some ISO-8859 variant (I'm guessing latin2 rather than latin1 based on your use of LATIN SMALL LETTER R WITH CARON), and that it is CONSISTENTLY so, you can use iconv() to re-encode it as UTF-8 before doing json_encode():

```
$foo = iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'utf8', $foo);
```

Comment: You have a typo - encoding is **utf-8** :) ! But with **utf-8** it is working ! :) (Sorry for Latin1, it is Latin2 that was a multi-typo too :D ) thanks ! :) (please correct and I will accept :) )

Comment: I don't understand your follow-up question (nor what it has to do with accepting the answer to the question here). Also, the "utf-8" vs. "utf8" is entirely based on your own configuration of iconv - what works on your system would have given an invalid encoding error on mine :)

Comment: well http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3629 standard specifies it with hyphen :) - in this issue it is better to stay with standards and default settings :) - And the follow up question - reverse the conversion - is it iconv('utf8', 'ISO-8859-2', $foo)?, because iconv('ISO-8859-2', 'utf8', $foo) is good for json => javascript display but wrong for php echo :)

Comment: Well, iconv isn't part of RFC 3629 (and note that RFC 3629 specifies it as "UTF-8" not "utf-8"), and the names being used in the iconv() call are actually how iconv decides what filename it needs to open for the conversion process; whatever those file(s) are named on your server is the name you should use, otherwise iconv will tell you it's an invalid encoding.

Comment: As for your "follow-up question", why would you assert that UTF-8 is "wrong for php echo"? I would actually recommend you do this conversion on the base data and start using UTF-8 everywhere, instead of mixing and matching like this.

Comment: I used print_r display - that might be the thing :D

Comment: You probably just need to set [default_charset](http://php.net/default-charset) in your php.ini to use UTF-8.

Comment: Isnt that same as mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");? Im not sure :D

Comment: No, they're not even related. default_charset dictates what PHP sends as the encoding in the HTTP headers.

Comment: Ah, you mean that :) well I usually dont have access directly to php.ini sometimes I can use php_ini fuctions() to temporarily change it :) - anyway I hope every modern hosting has its php.ini set to UTF-8 :) thanks for local-like tip anyway ! :)